# SVG or Canvas Machines Control Panels with HTML and Javascript

Tags: html, svg, panel

I need examples or demos of creating Control Panels for machines or devices with (HTML + JS and maybe using Canvas or SVG ) because I dont know how they are created

[image]

Like this panel and make elements clickable, I didn't find git repos or codes about that

Comment: SVG is the tool for this job.  You can design it with Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape, and then wire it up to your code by modifying the appropriate attributes.

Comment: Thats totally fine, but can you provide me with some examples?

Comment: Examples for what?  There are probably 100 elements in your image.  What specifically are you asking?

Comment: I found this example of an svg where multiple elements are interactive: https://codepen.io/belleepoque/pen/eNeyog There are things to drag and things to click that effect other things. It's probably a good place to start.

Comment: @aptriangle Thats very good , thanks a lot